# HTML5 H264 video sometimes not displaying

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video, media-source

Given this stream from an RTSP camera which produce H264 stream:

```
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.15:554':
  Metadata:
    title           : LIVE555 Streaming Media v2017.10.28
    comment         : LIVE555 Streaming Media v2017.10.28
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.881956, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 1600x900, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
```

I want to run ffmpeg and pipe its output to a HTML5 video component with MSE.

Everything is fine and smooth as long I run this ffmpeg command (piping is removed!):

```
$ ffmpeg -i 'rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.15:554' -c:v copy -an -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -f mp4
```

However it takes a bit time at the beginning.

I realized that the function `avformat_find_stream_info` makes about 15-20 seconds of delay on my system. [Here](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.8/group__lavf__decoding.html#gad42172e27cddafb81096939783b157bb) is the docs.

Now I have also realized that if I add `-probesize 32`, avformat_find_stream_info will return almost immediately, but it cause some warnings:

```
$ ffmpeg -probesize 32 -i 'rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.15:554' -c:v copy -an -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -f mp4

[rtsp @ 0x1b2b300] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
[rtsp @ 0x1b2b300] decoding for stream 0 failed
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.15:554':
  Metadata:
    title           : LIVE555 Streaming Media v2017.10.28
    comment         : LIVE555 Streaming Media v2017.10.28
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 1600x900, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
```

If I dump out this stream (into a file, test.mp4), all mediaplayers can play it perfectly.

However if I pipe this output into the HTML5 video with MSE, the stream sometimes displayed correctly, sometimes it just doesn't. **No warnings or error messages are printed on the console in the browser.**

From the second output I can see the fps is missing. I tried to set it up manually, but was not succeed (it seemed I could not change it manually).

**How can I avoid avformat_find_stream_info and have the HTML5 MSE playback if I know everything of the stream beforehand?**

### Update

According to @szatmary's comments and answers I have search for a h264 bitstream parser.

[This](https://github.com/mradionov/h264-bitstream-viewer) is what I found. I did also save the mp4 file which is not playable by HTML5 video, but by VLC it does, and I dropped into this analyser.

Here is a screenshot of my analysis:
[image]

Some facts here:

- until #66 there is no *type7 (SPS)* unit in the stream.
- 62 is the last PPS before the first SPS arrived.
- there are a lot of PPS even before 62.
- bitstream ends at #103.
- playing in VLC the stream is 20 seconds long.

I have several things to clear:

1. the #62 and #66 sps/pps units (or whatever) are holding metadata only for the next coming frames, or they can even refer to previous frames?
2. <s>VLC plays 20 seconds, is it possible that it scans the whole file before, then play the frames from #1 based on #62 and #66 infos? - if VLC would get the file as stream, in this case it might play only a few seconds (#66 - #103).</s>
3. **most important: what shall I do with the bitstream parser to make HTML5 video playing this data? <s>Shall I drop all the units before #62? Or before #66?</s>**

Now I'm really lost in this topic. I have created a video, with FFMPEG but this time I allowed it to finish its avformat_find_stream_info function.

Saved the video with the same methods as previously. VLC now plays 18 seconds (this is okay, I have a 1000 frame limitation in ffmpeg command).

However let's see now the bitstream information:

[image]

Now PPS and SPS are 130 and 133 respectively. This resulted a stream which is 2 sec shorter than before. (I guess)

**Now I have learned that in a correct parsed h264 there can still be a lot of units before the first SPS(/PPS).**

SO I would finetune my question above: **what shall I do with the bitstream parser to make HTML5 video playing this data?**

Also the bitstream parser I have found is not good, because it uses a binary wrapper => it can not be run purely on the client side.

I'm looking at [mp4box](https://github.com/gpac/mp4box.js) now.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I avoid avformat_find_stream_info and have the HTML5 MSE playback if I know everything of the stream beforehand?

You don't know everything of the stream beforehand. You don't know the resolution, or the bitrate, or the level or the profile, or the constraint flags. You don't know the scaling lists values, You don't know the VUI data, you don't know if CABAC is used.

The player needs all these things to play the video, and they are not know until the player, or ffmpeg sees the first sps/pps in the stream. By limiting the analyze duration you are telling ffmpeg to give up looking for it, so it cant be guaranteed to produce a valid stream. It may work sometimes, it may not other times, and it largely depends on what frame in the rstp stream you start on.

A possible solution would be to add more keyframes to the source video if you can, This will send the sps/pps more frequently. If you don't control the source stream, you must just wait until a sps/pps show up int the stream.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The stream is created with live555, and I can reconfigure it to send more keyframes. However if I do that I would lost some valuable performance with this particular stream, thus the solution wont be able to work with streams I have no control over. One thing would interest me a lot: even if I use ffmpeg with analyzeduration, the stream it produces is still playable let's say in VLC but not in html5 video.

Comment: And you wrote: "player needs all these things to play the video, and they are not know until the player...sees the first sps/pps in the stream." Can I go in that direction? Lets leave it in the player to find sps/pps. Whst do you think?

Comment: I am thinking of Broadway.js: https://github.com/mbebenita/Broadway. It is a pure js h264 decoder. Obviously not as effective as native html5 video, but as it is opensource, I can tweak it up to help for the html5 video finding those necessary sps/pps. Does this makes sense?

Comment: Waiting for the SPS/pps in the browser will not make it faster. It will take the same amount of time. You also don’t need a full decoder, just a bitstream parser.

Comment: szatmary: my top priority is to unload this task from the server. The server is slow, thus when calling avformat_find_stream_info, it consumes all the cpu resources for 20-30sec. Same stream with a med-power i7 server finishes under 1sec, and I can not even see anything on cpu usage. But during those 20-30 seconds the stream is constantly pushing data, so it will also mess up the sps/pps which I need to correct later on. On the i7 the sps/pps is good, not messed up. Putting this together, at the end I think it could be even faster if only the browser will wait for the sps/pps.

Comment: Trying to understand all the details in this amazingly huge topic. One (or more) thing is still not clear: if I don't let ffmpeg to wait for the first sps/pps, will it able to fragment the h264 stream to mp4? Or not at all?

Comment: Q has been updated with the bitstream-parser you have recommended (thank you!). Could you please check that out?

Comment: How could I utilize a bitstream parser i.e. http://thumb.co.il to help mse with the playing?